# Adding IntelliJ Language injections to a library

Tags: intellij-idea, jdbi

Can I retrofit a library with IntelliJ's Language injections? I know how to [add them to my own code](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-language-injections.html) via annotations or comments, but I'd like to have the syntax coloring in JDBI's `@SqlUpdate` and `@SqlQuery` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position your text cursor on the query literal, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select `Inject language or reference`. Then choose your desired SQL dialect and you should be set.

[image: here's how the language injection intention looks]

Comment: Thanks, works great. I was looking for a way to add it in code, but I suppose doing this in the IDE will do fine.

Comment: But, this requires injecting the language manually in every single call site. Can be very tedious especially for a SQL or JSON library. Is there a way to do this once?